# XML Parsing on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

How to return data in format:

```
Column Name t01     t02     t03     t04
Data        c01     c02     c03     c04

<orders xmlns="www address">
    <order>
        <order-date>2019-09-05</order-date>
        <created-by>storefront</created-by>
        <original-order-no>000001</original-order-no>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <taxation>gross</taxation>
        <invoice-no>0099999</invoice-no>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t01">c01</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t02">c02</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t03">c03</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t04">c04</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>    
    </order>
</orders>
```

Comment: Will there always be four possible attributes, i.e. no t05, t06 etc?

Comment: unfortunately no. some times can be 8, next time 10. But i will take only 4

Comment: SQL Server is declarative by design,  Having variable attributes will force you down a path of Dynamic SQL  ... UNLESS ... you are willing to set a maximum number of attributes and allow the excess to be null.

Comment: John i will take only 4 attributes. But in xml files sometimes can be them 8, 10...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question there's one thing not clear: The naming of the output columns.

In your expected output they are named like their `attribute-id`. But in your comments it sounds, like you are picking the first 4 attributes and you want to omit the rest.

I want to show two approaches, pick the one you like more:

```
DECLARE @mockupTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockupTable VALUES
(N'<orders xmlns="www address">
    <order>
        <order-date>2019-09-05</order-date>
        <created-by>storefront</created-by>
        <original-order-no>000001</original-order-no>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <taxation>gross</taxation>
        <invoice-no>0099999</invoice-no>
        <custom-attributes>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t01">c01</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t02">c02</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t03">c03</custom-attribute>
            <custom-attribute attribute-id="t04">c04</custom-attribute>
        </custom-attributes>    
    </order>
</orders>');
```

--This query will use the `attribute-id` to pick the corresponding attribute.
--We can savely return this with the same name
--If your XML does not have the corresponding attribute, there will be a NULL value

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'www address')
SELECT o.value('(order-date/text())[1]','date') OrderDate
      --As in your other questions
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="t01"]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS t01 
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="t02"]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS t02
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="t03"]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS t03 
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[@attribute-id="t04"]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS t04 
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('/orders/order') A(o);
```

--This one is easier. It will pick just the first four attributes, no matter what id they have.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'www address')
SELECT o.value('(order-date/text())[1]','date') OrderDate
      --As in your other questions
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[1]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS ca1 
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[2]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS ca2
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[3]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS ca3 
      ,o.value('(custom-attributes/custom-attribute[4]/text())[1]','varchar(100)') AS ca4 
FROM @mockupTable t
CROSS APPLY t.YourXml.nodes('/orders/order') A(o);
```